# Merging Two Lists - Loops

Tags: list-manipulation

I have 2 lists. For example,

```
list1 = {{a,b}, {c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h}}

list2 = {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}}
```

I want to merge them such that I get the result:

```
list3 = {{1,a,b}, {2,c, d}, {3,e, f}, {4,g, h}}
```

and the method generalizes to a large number of sublists.

How can one write a loop to execute this sequence of operations?

Comment: `Flatten /@ Transpose[{list2, list1}]` good enough?

Comment: @BlacKow no, `Join[list2, list1, 2]` :)

Comment: I would avoid looking for a loop to achieve this sort of stuff! There is always a better way in Mathematica.

Comment: related: [113630](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/113630/5478) together with topics linked there.

Comment: @Kuba.. yeah, I agree... There should be a solution involving `Dot` though :)

Comment: Surely this *already has an answer* elsewhere, e.g. [(189)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/189/121), [(13748)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13748/121), [(51407)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51407/121),
[(67423)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/67423/121),
[(83575)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83575/121),
[(98406)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/98406/121),
[(99350)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/99350/121),
[(99985)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/99985/121), or is *easily found in the documentation.*

Comment: `MapThread[Join, {list2, list1}]`

Answer (score 1):

Either transpose one list against the other or thread over them. Then flatten each sublist. Internally operations are looped over the lists all right, but this is how one normally does things in Mathematica.

```
transposed = Transpose[{list2, list1}];
threaded = Thread[{list2, list1}];
Flatten /@ transposed
```

> {{1, a, b}, {2, c, d}, {3, e, f}, {4, g, h}}

```
SameQ[Flatten /@ transposed, Flatten /@ threaded]
```

> True

Answer (score 0):

One way could be

```
list3 = Partition[Flatten@Riffle[list2,list1], 3]
```

There a few things to watch out for though. `Riffle` truncates lists if the two arguments are not of the same length. Also, a more general way to generate your `list2` might be to use `Range`, for example,

```
 Range[Length@list1]
```

So all together you might try

```
list3 = Partition[Flatten@Riffle[
   Range[Length@list1],
   list1], 3]
```